# Change OS language for Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, windows, language

Is it possible to change the language of Windows 7 **Professional** by installing a language pack or somehow?

As far as I have searched, it can be done for Ultimate or Enterprise by installing additional language packs. But for Windows 7 Professional, I found only one solution which I cannot accept : reinstall in the desired language.

Is there no way to keep the current OS instalation and install a language pack or somehow?

Comment: The only official way would be upgrading to the Ultimate (or Enterprise) edition, which fully support multiple languages out of the box. The workaround would be manually installing the language pack(s), but that breaks the EULA and it's not supported at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change Windows 7 display language on Home Premium version?](http://superuser.com/questions/77166/can-i-change-windows-7-display-language-on-home-premium-version)

Answer (score 1):

As said on http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-change-system-language-of-windows-7-home/d58fb37b-cb02-41c8-986f-22582fd35a12, by Microsoft:

> You will need to upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate for this capability. Only Windows 7 Ultimate includes Multilingual User
>   Interface (Language Pack) support. You can then install the English
>   Language Pack from under Regional and Language settings in Control
>   Panel.
>
> You can do an Anytime Upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate which will preserve your personal files and settings:
>
> Learn more: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-anytime-upgrade